# Coffeescript/cake on Windows: Cakefile can't be found

Tags: windows, node.js, coffeescript

I have a ~\Cakefile that looks like this:

```
task 'say:hello', 'Howdy!', (options) ->
    console.log 'Hello, world!'
```

But running `cake` (which resolves to `C:\Users\bstraub\AppData\Roaming\npm\cake.cmd` since it was installed with `npm`) gives this error:

```
Error: Cakefile not found in C:\Users\bstraub
```

The file exists. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path.exists` and `path.existsSync` were [broken for Windows in node 0.6.9](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2635). Updating to 0.6.13 corrects this, and `cake` works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the file is really called `Cakefile` and not `CakeFile` or something.
2. Check if `~\Cakefile` maps to `C:\Users\bstraub\Cakefile`.
   The `~` might map to some other dir, depending on your system config
   (e.g., with cygwin, git-bash, or a funny corporate env var setup).
3. Check if `cd ~` really brings you to `C:\Users\bstraub`

Comment: All totally okay. Though the use of `~` is a little misleading; this happens no matter what my cwd is.  Inside node, `fs.readFileSync('./Cakefile').toString()` works as expected.